# Python excel edit with openpyxel changes date in another cell

Tags: excel, pandas, date, edit, openpyxl

When loading an already existing excel file with openpyxl, changing a value in a cell and then saving the file, another value (a date) gets changed as well. I can't seem to find the reason/error behind this strange behaviour.

This is my excel file `dates.xlsx`:

```
Title   Date
Date1   01.01.1900
Date2   02.01.1900
Date3   03.01.1900
```

This is how I modify the value of a cell and save the changes:

```py
from openpyxl import load_workbook

fileName = "./dates.xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(filename=fileName)
sheet = wb.active
sheet.cell(row=4, column=3).value = "new value"
wb.save(fileName)
wb.close()
```

Expected result:

```
Title   Date
Date1   01.01.1900
Date2   02.01.1900
Date3   03.01.1900   new value
```

Actual result:

```
Title   Date
Date1   00.01.1900
Date2   02.01.1900
Date3   03.01.1900   new value
```

This only happens with dates. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is really to do with the specification of dates in OOXML and some bugs in OOXML. To workaround this you can set `iso_dates=True` when saving the workbook. This will at least save an unambiguous representation in the XML. What other applications make of it (Excel thinks the serial 0 is the 0th January 1900) is another matter. Basically, the file format is not at all suitable for historical dates.

Comment: If i put `wb.iso_dates = True` before saving (`wb.save()` hasn't got a `iso_dates` argument), The value for 01.01.1900 changes to `#VALUE!` (as a text!). The funny thing is: If my list starts with 02.01.1900, the error doesn't occur at all. Something seems buggy here, as you already mentioned. I'll look if I find another workaround.

Comment: If you're seeing `#VALUE` then you probably have a formula in the relevant cells.